# Laravel 5.2 if user try to log in with a wrong password three times, lock the account

Tags: php, authentication, locking, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel.  So far I used CodeIgniter.

I am trying to implement a system to lock the user if the user tried
to login with a wrong password three times.

User use email address and password to login.

This is what I did.

1. In /laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticateUsers.php
   I can write a code to redirect the user to a new page if the user tried to 
   login three times with a wrong password.

The code:

```
return redirect('/lockout')->with('warning', 'You are permanently log out. Please contact the System Administrator');
```

Next I want to:

1. Retrieve the email address user entered in the login form
2. Find the email address in locked users table.
3. put a check mark in "Locked" column

   in a controller.

Am I in the correct track.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lock the account if a user try to login with wrong password is not a great idea. Anyone can lock anybody's account using their email address and wrong password. Instead you can limit the login attempt using throttlelogins traits in the controller.

```
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins ;
```

You can use `ThrottleMiddleware` of  [GrahamCampbell Laravel throttle](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle) and limit the attempts and login delay time.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('foo', ['middleware' => 'GrahamCampbell\Throttle\Http\Middleware\ThrottleMiddleware:50,30', function () {
      return 'Why herro there!';
}]);
```

This will setup a middleware for that url with a limit of 50 hits and a retention time of 30 mins.

Comment: Thank you very much Sanzeeb Aryal.  I was waiting for some help.  I did the same with this code in AuthController : protected $maxLoginAttempts = 3; // Amount of bad attempts user can make
 //protected $lockoutTime = 2678400; // Time for which user is going to be blocked in seconds.

My client wants to lock out the user.  Any suggestions.

Comment: @user1166240 well, if you insist on locking the users. With `$maxloginAttempts` of a particular email address  you can softdelete the user, so that you can reopen the account.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sanzeeb Aryal.  Can you elaborate your answer please.  What is softdelete mean and $maxloginAttempts is a variable in Laravel login system?

Comment: Sorry for $maxloginAttempts question. Thanks again. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: see [Soft delete](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#soft-deleting), and i'm not sure how to get the instance of throttle login attempts. I guess, throttle blocks the ip address to login with the attempts and this is different from your scenario. couldn't help much.

Comment: Thank you very much Sanzeeb Aryal.  I will select your answer.